# How does Young's inequality reduce to the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going through Carothers Real Analysis to study for my qualifying exams, and came across this unjustified statement, that Youngs inequality (for $p > 1$ and q such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ we have that for $a, b \geq 0$, $ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{a^q}{q}$), when $p=q=2$, reduces to the arithmetic geometric mean inequality $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}$. I tried manipulating youngs inequality but cant seem to derive the arithmetic geometric mean inequality from it. How is it done?

Comment: Young's inequality : $$ ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $\sqrt a$, $\sqrt b$ for $a,b$, respectively.

Comment: Oh duh. Lol thanks